# Qt Graphic scenes with external 2D engine

Tags: qt, widget, 2d, graphic

I am using Qt 4.8 and its 2D engine (QGraphicScene) to display some schematics.
These scenes have a lot of graphic elements, and Qt struggle to render them.

Is there a way to uses Qt with another 2D engine (Oxygene, GODOT ...) and renders to a Widget ?

Thank you all.

Comment: You could try converting your current QGraphicsScene implementation to Open GL then you might be able to get some performance improvements using an QOpenGLWidget. Alternatively you could use something like SDL2 to render to a buffer which you can then render onto a QWidget, though better performance isn't guarenteed. Failing that you could try to make optimisations to your current QGraphicsScene implementation. Also note that lots of performance improvements have been made in newer Qt versions, and in 5.9 Qt Quick Scene Graphs are supposed to be significantly faster that QGraphicsViews!

Comment: I think I'll migrate to Qt 5.9. The project I'm working on was historically developed under Qt 4.8. From what I gather, Qt 5.9 ensure backward compatibility. Thank you.